# In ASP.NET Core 2.2, How To Get Base URL in startup service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got an asp.net core 2.2 project with a startup.cs service that does an async REST GET call back to my current site and then returns the result (View Component using DI) back to the razor view.

In the service, I want to call "/api/sessions" and not "http://localhost:3433/api/sessions". I know I could use the ~ ta helper if I were inside my razor page to get the base path to the web server, but how can I get that from a service?

Here is my service and relevant code.

From: SessionsService.cs (this is where I don't want http://localhost but just ~/

public class Session
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

```
public class SessionsService : ISessionsService
{
    public async Task<List<Session>> GetSessions(int speakerId)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:50463/api/sessions");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var sessions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Session>>(result);
        return sessions;
    }

}
```

From: startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddTransient<ISessionsService, SessionsService>();
```

From: index.cshtml

```
<vc:speaker-card speaker="@speaker" ></vc:speaker-card>
```

From: SpeakerCardViewComponent.cs

```
{
    private ISessionsService _sessionsService;

    public SpeakerCardViewComponent(ISessionsService sessionsService)
    {
        _sessionsService = sessionsService;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        Speaker speaker)
    {
        var sessions = await _sessionsService.GetSessions(101);
        speaker.Sessions = sessions;
        return View(speaker);
    }
}
```

ANSWER AS SUGGESTED BY KIRK LARKIN FOLLOWS:

```
   public async Task<List<Session>> GetSessions(int speakerId,string baseUrl)
    {

        var uri = new Uri($"{baseUrl}api/sessions");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        var sessions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Session>>(result);
        return sessions;
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISessionsService, SessionsService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();



    public class SpeakerCardViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
    private ISessionsService _sessionsService;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SpeakerCardViewComponent(ISessionsService sessionsService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _sessionsService = sessionsService;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        Speaker speaker)
    {
        var isHttps = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.IsHttps;
        var baseUrl = isHttps ? "https://" : "http://"
                                             + _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value
                                             + "/";


        var sessions = await _sessionsService.GetSessions(speaker.SpeakerId, baseUrl);
        speaker.Sessions = sessions;
        return View(speaker);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `IHttpContextAccessor` in `SessionService`, which means you can get hold of the current request and look at it's URL based properties to build up what you need. Having said that, it's usually a bad idea to call back into your own host using HTTP.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. This is for course-ware and it's better then creating another project and another http endpoint the user has to start.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I did consider that but wanted to just raise it to be sure. Do you think the `IHttpContextAccessor` approach is of value?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I don't love the answer, but it works. I posted the changes in the question above.

Comment: That's probably the proper way to do it since my sessionsService itself should probably not reach out for it. I thought of passing it from the razor view page and that felt even worse.

Comment: I just realised you're doing it in the `ViewComponent` now, which means you can drop all the `IHttpContextAcessor` stuff and just use: `var baseUrl = new Uri(Request.GetEncodedUrl()).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);`.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize I had access to the Request object there. I was thinking that I'd  need a context for that like what gets passed into the Tag Helpers (still not sure why I have access)

Comment: Why do you even want to make a server-side HTTP request to an endpoint of the same server you are executing on? Why don’t you just call some shared backend logic for that?

Comment: For courseware. @poke